# NTP synchro issue

Tags: dc

Hello does anyone know the solution to NTP synch from DC , i'm trying to change the source from "Local CMOS Clock " to "time.windows.com,0x9"

1. I mean we can see the NtpServer : time.windows.com,0x9 but the source is always "Local CMOS Clock "
   (set as NTP Server)
2. and the sync command doesn't work as mentionned in the screenshot
3. And when i do the command:

```
> w32tm /stripchart /computer:time.windows.com
Suivi de time.windows.com [51.145.123.29:123].
L’heure actuelle est 16/05/2023 14:00:26.
14:00:26, erreur: 0x800705B4
14:00:29, erreur: 0x800705B4
```

[image]